# Proof that no segment is compact

Tags: general-topology

Does anyone have a simple proof (without using any theorems of compactness) that no segment of the form $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact?

*Definitions:*  For any subset $E$ of a metric space $X$, an *open cover* is a collection of sets $\{G_\alpha\}$ which are open in $X$, such that $E \subset \bigcup_\alpha G_\alpha$.  $E$ is *compact* if every one of its open covers has a finite open subcover.

*Proof so far:*  Let $G_n = (a + \frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n})$.  Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_n = (a, b)$.  [Is there a concise way to prove this fact?]  So $G = \{G_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $(a, b)$, but $G$ has no finite open subcover.  [Why is that true?]

Comment: The first assertion follows from the Archimedean property and the second assertion follows from the fact that the union of any finite subcover of $\{ G_n \}$ is contained in $G_n$ for some $n$ (the maximum $n$ which appears in the subcover).

Comment: If you don't see _intuitively_ why the proof works, draw a picture. In topology, drawing a picture almost always helps immensely.

Comment: I just found an answer to the question "[Is there a concise way to prove this fact?]"  For every $x \in (a, b)$, the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$ asserts that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > \max \{\frac{1}{x-a}, \frac{1}{b-x}\}$, so that $na + a < nx < nb - 1 \Rightarrow a + \frac{1}{n} < x < b - \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow x \in G_n$.  Thus for every $x \in (a, b)$, $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n G_n = G$.

Comment: Qiaochu, you don't need the Archimedian property to know that $(a,b)$ is not compact. Rather, you just need to know that the order is dense. Even non-Archimedian dense orders have open intervals non-compact, since $(a,b)=\bigcup_{a\lt c\lt d\lt b}(c,d)$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: @JDH, you're right--but for that proof, you do need to use the density property of $\mathbb{R}$, which is an immediate consequence of the Archimedean Property anyway.  (To show that any $x \in (a, b)$ is in the union of that open cover, you use the fact that there exists $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < c < x$ and $x < d < b$.)

Comment: Yes, I agree, you need only density. The $\mathbb{R}$ order is dense because we can take averages. (So we don't need to deal with the Archimedian property.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one gave a full answer, here's a proof using the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$.  Thanks for the original comments, and please let me know if anything here is wrong!

To show that $(a, b)$ is not compact, we just need one example
of an open cover that has no finite open subcover.
We will use the cover
$$\{ G_n \} = \left\{ \left( a + \frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n} \right) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$
(If this gives us an invalid segment such as $(1, 0)$, treat it an empty element.)

Why does $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ cover $(a, b)$?
Well, for any element $x \in (a, b)$, the Archimedean Property provides an $n \in \mathbb{N}$
such that $n > \max \{ \frac{1}{x - a}, \frac{1}{b - x} \}$.  Then
$$nx - na > 1 \text{ and } nb - nx > 1 \Rightarrow na + 1 < nx < nb - 1 \Rightarrow x \in \left( a + \frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n} \right).$$
Thus every element of $(a, b)$ is in $G_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
so $(a, b) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$.

Why does $\{ G_n \}$ have no finite subcover?  Well, for any $i > j$,
$a + \frac{1}{i} < a + \frac{1}{j} < b - \frac{1}{j} < b - \frac{1}{i}$, so that $G_i \supset G_j$.
Thus for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k < \infty$,
$\bigcup_{n=1}^k G_n = G_k = (a + \frac{1}{k}, b - \frac{1}{k})$.
But $(a, b) \not\subset G_k$---since, for example, $a + \frac{1}{2k} \in (a, b)$
but $\notin (a + \frac{1}{k}, b - \frac{1}{k})$.